# Want to use replica of plugin that i already have with little changes in osgi

Tags: osgi

I have on osgi plugin but I want to use same plugin with some changes in classes and want to load/install both plugin is it possible? how?

Answer (score 1):

In OSGi there is one simple rule. No two bundles can have the same symbolic name and version. So make sure when you change the classes you also change either symbolic name or version in the Manifest. Then it should be no problem.

Comment: hi I am using different symbolic name and version but my directory structure of plugins are same so it will throw classcast exception when i tried to run both plugin in my project

Comment: Did it actually throw ClassCastException? If so, show the stack trace. Or are you just guessing that it will? Don't guess... try.

Comment: A classcast exception can occur easily if you export the same package in two bundles. Can you explain some more why you create the bundles and how they communicate with other bundles?